# "Incompatible peer dependency" error when upgrading Angular 5 to 9

Tags: angular

I want to upgrade my Angular application from version 5 to version 9. I get the following dependency error while doing so:

> Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.7"). Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "5.2.11" (extended), would install "9.1.7"). Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.5.0", would install "6.5.5"). Package "awesome-typescript-loader" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "^2", would install "3.8.3").

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.7").
                 Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "5.2.11" (extended), would install "9.1.7").
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.5.0", would install "6.5.5").
                  Package "awesome-typescript-loader" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "^2", would install "3.8.3").

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments. Comments may or may not be shown initially, and show up in order of votes, not chronologically. See also [ask].

Comment: Try: `ng update --all --force`